# CLRegion background monitoring not occuring

Tags: ios, core-location, clregion, region-monitoring

In my project settings > target > Capabilities I have Background Modes ON with "Location Updates" checked.

[image]

[image]

AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.storyController = [StoryController sharedController];
    self.storyController.locationManager.delegate = self;

 ... etc initializing VC ...

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"entered region, %@", region.identifier);
    [self handleRegionEvent:region];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"exited region, %@", region.identifier);
    [self handleRegionEvent:region];
}

- (void)handleRegionEvent:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"handle region");
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState ==
        UIApplicationStateActive) {
        NSLog(@"handle region local");
        UILocalNotification *n = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        n.alertBody = @"LOCAL";
        n.soundName = @"Default"; //Coffee Man?
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:n];
    } else {
        if ([[StoryController sharedController] readyForNextChapter]) {
            UILocalNotification *n = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            n.alertBody = @"New ☕ Story";
            n.soundName = @"Default"; //Coffee Man?
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:n];
        }
    }
}
```

StoryController

```
+ (id)sharedController {
    static StoryController *myController = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t token;
    dispatch_once(&token, ^{
        myController = [[StoryController alloc] init];
    });

    return myController;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"monitored regions: %@", self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
```

I am monitoring for the region later on with:

```
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:g.coordinate radius:1000 identifier:"My Store"];
region.notifyOnEntry = true;
region.notifyOnExit = true;

NSLog(@"%d", [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]);
[[[StoryController sharedController] locationManager] startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

I am not receiving any notifications when I leave or enter a 1km range with the app backgrounded.

How do I make this work? When I log out my monitored regions, I do see the lat & lng are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to make sure you're doing.

1. checking for availability of region monitoring
2. make sure your locationManager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways

Some systems simply don't support region monitoring, and region monitoring will never work unless your authorizationStatus is .authorizedAlways, only then can it monitor in the background.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html